# Error: [object Object] on Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I keep getting an error when I run the javascript below in Firebug. I've tried changing multiple things and it still outputs the error. I am working with an api to retrieve information from the XML and then output it onto the screen but I keep getting an object error. Can someone see why?? Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#searchbtn').bind('click' || 'enter',function(e) {
        if ($.trim($('#searchBox').val()) !== '') {
            $('#videos').append('<img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading" />');
            getVideos(e);
        }
    });
});

function getVideos(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = 'text='+$('#searchBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getVideos.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        type: 'POST',
        data: text,
        success: function(data) {                               
            $('#videos').append("<h1>The following events match your search!</h1>");

            var xmlString = data;

            if ($(xmlString).find('feed').children('entry').length == 0) {
                $('#videos').append('<p class="noResults">Sorry, no results for you! Try searching again!</p>');
            } else {
                var videoTitle = [];

                $(xmlString).find('title').each(function() 
                { 
                videoTitle.push($(this).text()) });

                $('#videos').append('<ul>');

                $(xmlString).find('entry').each(function(i) {
                    if (i == '40') {
                        return(false);
                    }
                    var vidInfo = '';
                    vidInfo += "<p>"+videoTitle[i]+"</p>";
                    $('#videos ul').append('<li>'+vidInfo+'</li>');
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
        }

    })
};
```

Comment: can you please put your exact error ?

Comment: As Chuck replied, you are adding a string `Error: ` to your `data` object.

Answer (score 26):

When you append an object to a string, it gets its `toString` method called, which for a plain object just gives the infamous "[object Object]". To log an object, you should just pass it straight into the `console.log` function as an argument, like so:

```
console.log('Error:', data);
```

Comment: @LE12: You should replace the line that reads `console.log('Error: ' + data);` with that code, yes.