# Axios interceptor does not give me my exception object

Tags: javascript, axios

I created a response interceptor for axios and I want to check something and be able to throw new error there.

This is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
});

const responseInterceptor = (error) => {
  throw new Error({
    name: 'John',
    age: 40,
  });
};

axiosApi.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, responseInterceptor);

const get = async (url) => {
  return await axiosApi
    .get(url, {
      crossDomain: true,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      return response?.data;
    });
};

export default function Home() {
  get('/user/1').then(
    (data) => {},
    (error) => {
      console.log(error); // Here, error is not an object. It's [object Object]
    }
  );
  return <div>hi</div>;
}
```

I read about `[object Object]` and it seems that somewhere axios turns my JS object into a string.

How can I get the `error` as the original object in my error handler?

Comment: Why do you believe `console.log` isn't turning the object into a string?

Comment: @possum, because `console.log({name:'John'})` prints the object. It's that simple.

Comment: Your problem is not axios converting something to a string,  it's that you're misusing the `Error` class.  `Error` accepts a string as an argument and when you pass it your object in your interceptor, the interpreter has no choice but to convert it to a string, which is why you're getting the `[object Object]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156309/error-object-object-on-javascript

Comment: @possum, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) says it's possible.

Comment: Yes, and you're not doing what that documentation says you need to implement to get an object.  It's not pass it as the constructor argument and nothing in the link you posted suggests it should be.